# Loading model in Stanford NER

Tags: maven, stanford-nlp

I am using Maven. Have dependencies for *stanford-corenlp 3.7.0* and *stanford-corenlp models*. The demo code works fine, with some default model. How do I switch models using : *CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(String loadpath)*
I tried a couple of options like

- /models/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.caseless.ser.gz
- englishPCFG.caseless.ser.gz
- /englishPCFG.caseless.ser.gz

No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list of available models:

```
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.nowiki.3class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.nodistsim.crf.ser.gz
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.nodistsim.crf.ser.gz
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.nowiki.3class.nodistsim.crf.ser.gz
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.nodistsim.crf.ser.gz
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz
```

You need the English models jar available at this link:

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

For Maven you need stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models-english.jar as well in your dependencies.